# Instead of using sizeof(type), use sizeof *p,is it safe and correct?

Tags: c, malloc

Is this safe to use,This code compiled  with *gcc 4.9.2* without any error or warning

```
widget *p;
...
p = malloc(sizeof *p);
```

I found this on **SEI CERT C Coding Standard** website.

Click [here](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/MEM02-C.+Immediately+cast+the+result+of+a+memory+allocation+function+call+into+a+pointer+to+the+allocated+type#space-menu-link-content)
 -- no type mismatch issues, no need for casting.   You allocate the right amount of memory every time.

```
struct widget;
typedef struct widget widget_t;

struct gadget;
typedef struct gadget gadget_t;

widget_t *newWidget(void)
{
    widget_t *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
    if (p) 
        /* initialize members of *p as necessary */
    return p;
} 

gadget_t *newGadget(void)
{
    gadget_t *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
    if (p)
        /* initialize members of *p as necessary */
    return p;
}

void deleteWidget(widget_t **p)
{
     /* delete any subelements of *p */
     free(*p);
     *p = NULL;
}

void deleteGadget(gadget_t **p)
{
    /* delete any subelements of *p */
    free(*p);
    *p = NULL;
}

...

widget_t *p = newWidget();
gadget_t *g = newGadget();

if (p)
    /* do stuff with p */

if (g)
    /* do stuff with g */
...
deleteWidget(&p); 
deleteGadget(&g);
```

Comment: `p = malloc(sizeof *p)` is easier to _review_ than `p = malloc(sizeof (some_type))`.  The 2nd form obliges a check of "is the type right".  The first is correct by construction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sizeof operator has the following definition

```
sizeof unary-expression
sizeof ( type-name )
```

Thus in this declaration

```
widget_t *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
```

there is used the first form of the operator where the expression `*p` is an unary expression and has the type of `widget_t`.

Thus these declarations

```
widget_t *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
widget_t *p = malloc(sizeof( widget_t ) );
```

are totally equivalent.

The first declaration is preferable because the expression in the sizeof operator does not depend on the actual type. That is the type of the pointer can be changed but the declaration will be valid without any other changes.

In C there is no need to cast the pointer returned from malloc to the type of the assigned lvalue because a pointer of the type void * may be assigned to pointer to object of any type. It is sometimes used (and moreover sometimes useful) to  make the program self-documented.

Comment: widget_t *p = malloc(sizeof( widget_t ) ); then why'r we use typecasting?

Comment: @bhura Where do you see a typecasting?

Comment: widget_t *p =(widget_t *) malloc(sizeof( widget_t ) ); @Vlad from Moscow i think that one is the correct format.

Comment: @bhura This is redundant in C becaus a pointer of the type void * may be assigned to pointer to any object type. The casting sometimes is used for self-documentation of code.

Comment: @bhura: A cast is only necessary in C++ (which does not allow implicit conversion of `void *` to other pointer types) or in a pre-C89 implementation (where `void *` didn’t exist and the `*alloc` functions returned `char *`).  Otherwise, it’s unnecessary and only adds to the maintenance burden.

Comment: @JohnBode "only adds to the maintenance burden" is a totally wrong statement. Using casting allows in C to escape many errors that are hardly to find and sometimes makes code self-documented.

Comment: I know that parenthesis are not mandatory for `sizeof(X)` when X is not a type. But... PLEASE... use parenthesis. A senior SW engineer, when I entered my previous job, used to say "Parenthesis are free!!!". Wise words.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: I need some examples, because my experience over three decades runs exactly counter to that.  Getting rid of explicit casts on `*alloc` calls got rid of a lot of heartburn for me.  `p = malloc( N * sizeof *p );` always does the right thing, *regardless of the type of `p`* - you don't *need* to know any type information here.  And, by leaving the cast off, you don't risk suppressing a useful diagnostic.

Comment: @JohnBode Consider two examples. p = malloc( sizeof( *p ) ); Can you say what is the type of p? Can you say whether it is a correct memory allocation? For example between the declaration of the pointer p and this statement there can be several screens (or pages). You need to scroll the source code forward and backward to determine the validaty of the allocation and the declaration of p. Moreover p can be declared even in a different module.

Comment: @JohnBode Another example. Consider the code p = malloc( sizeof( int[3][4] ) ); Can you be sure that it is a valid allocation? For example p can be declared like int ( * )[5]. Using the casting like p = ( int ( * )[4] )malloc( sizeof( int[3][4] ) ); the compiler can found an error at the compilation time.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: "`p = malloc( sizeof( *p) )`; Can you say what is the type of p?"  No - and it *doesn't matter*.  All that matters is that the right number of bytes get allocated for the target, which `p = malloc( sizeof *p );` does *regardless of the presence or absence of a cast.*.  The cast doesn't buy you *anything* in terms of the number of bytes allocated, only in how the resulting pointer value is interpreted.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: "Consider the code p = malloc( sizeof( int[3][4] ) ); Can you be sure that it is a valid allocation?" No, which is why I use the `p = malloc( sizeof *p );` idiom.

Comment: @JohnBode You are wrong. For starters readers of the code will not know what type of the object will be stored in the allocated memory. It is difficult to read such a code. Moreover for example the allocated memory may be reinterpreted. Maybe the valid allocation should look like p = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) ); while the type of p is char *.

Comment: @JohnBode You may not use p = malloc( sizeof *p ); because the type of p is int ( * )[6]. You need to use a multiplier.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow *Using casting allows in C to escape many errors that are hardly to find and sometimes makes code self-documented.*  Yes, it does that.  But casting can also hide errors.  How many questions here does the simple `connect()` call generate because an incorrect value was cast to `struct sockaddr`?  Casting is a tool - like a hammer.  You can drive a nail with it, or you can smash your thumb.

Comment: @Cubo78 Hm... `int x = (((((((7)))))));` – just joking... Tend to agree on sizeof, but in other situations too many parentheses can make code heavy to read as well. Luckily, we are not in C++, where in a few cases parentheses actually *can* change semantics (`decltype(auto) f() { int n = 7; return (n); }` and you get a dangling reference to local variable `n`, comparable to a pointer to local variable in C...).

Comment: @Aconcagua don't underestimate psychedelic effects of `int x = (((((((7)))))));`! :) As a general rule, parenthesis make things clear concerning operators priority. Add parenthesis until ten developers without a C manual agree on the behaviour of an expression. ;)

Answer (score 5):

It's a good coding practice!

Imagine this code

```
struct structv1 *p1 = malloc(sizeof (struct structv1));
struct structv1 *p2 = malloc(sizeof *p2);
```

gets changed to

```
struct structv2 *p1 = malloc(sizeof (struct structv2));
//     ^^^^^^^^                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// two changes! maybe the programmer forgets one of them
struct structv2 *p2 = malloc(sizeof *p2);
//     ^^^^^^^^
// one change only. the argument to malloc is already correct
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `sizeof *p` instead of `sizeof (type)` is safe with one exception - if `p` is an uninitialized or invalid pointer to a variable-length array, then the behavior is undefined.  For example:

```
size_t rows, cols;
...
T (*p)[cols] = malloc( rows * sizeof *p );  // *p is undefined here
```

For every type *except* variably-modified types, the operand of `sizeof` is not evaluated.  For variable-length arrays, it *is* evaluated, and since `p` is invalid until after the `malloc` call completes, applying the `*` operator to it results in undefined behavior.

[Chapter and verse](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> **6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators**
> ...
> 4 The unary `*` operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a function, the result is
> a function designator; if it points to an object, the result is an lvalue designating the
> object. If the operand has type ‘‘pointer to *type*’’, the result has type ‘‘*type*’’. If an
> invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary `*` operator is
> undefined.<sup>102)</sup>
> ...
> **6.5.3.4 The sizeof and _Alignof operators**
> ...
> 2 The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
> expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of
> the operand. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array
> type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an
> integer constant.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>102) ... 
> Among the invalid values for dereferencing a pointer by the unary `*` operator are a null pointer, an
> address inappropriately aligned for the type of object pointed to, and the address of an object after the
> end of its lifetime.</sub>

Now, I've used the above code a number of times and have never had any issues, but that's not a guarantee of anything - I've only ever used it on one particular architecture (x68) and with a limited range of compilers.  There's no guarantee that it won't blow up *spectacularly* on some oddball architecture.

It's an incredibly useful idiom, though, and I kind of wish the standard were worded better to properly define it.  I don't have a copy of the very latest (2011 is the most recent I have access to), so I don't know if they've tweaked that language any.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes, it's safe.

`sizeof` isn't a function; [it's an *operator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof). Used as you've shown, it  returns the size in bytes of the object representation of the *type* of the expression. The expression itself isn't evaluated at run-time; it instead feeds a *type* to the `sizeof` operator at compile time, and thus no harm or foul.